# ddply type functionality on multiple datafrmaes

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr, apply

I have two dataframes that are structured as follows:

Dataframe A:

```
     id sqft traf month
1  1030   16   35     1
1  1030   15   32     2
2  1027    1   31     1
2  1027    2   31     2
```

Dataframe B:

```
      id price frequency month day
 1  1030     8       196     1   1
 2  1030     9       101     1  15
 3  1030    10       156     1  30
 4  1030     3       137     2   1
 5  1030     7       190     2  15
 6  1027     6       188     1   1
 7  1027     1       198     1  15
 8  1027     2       123     1  30
 9  1027     4       185     2   1
 10 1027     5       122     2  15
```

I want to output certain types of summary statistics (centered around each unique ID) from both these columns. This would be easy with ddply if say I wanted the mean price for each ID for each month (split by id and month) from Dataframe B or if I wanted the average ratio of sqft to traf for each id (split by id).

But what would be a potential solution if I wanted to make combined variables from both dataframes. For instance, how would I get the average price for each id/month (Dataframe B) divided by sqft for each id/month?

The varying frequencies at of the dataframes are measured makes combining them not easily doable. The only solution I've found so far is to ddply the first dataframe to extract average sqft/id/month and then pass that value into a second ddply call on the second dataframe.

Is there a more efficient/less convoluted way to do this? I would be splitting both dataframes on the same variables (id and month).

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: apologies, for the sake of the question, I just manually changed the IDs to match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of the sample data, you could `merge` the two data sets like this (by specifying `all.y = TRUE` you can make sure that all rows of dfb are kept and, in this case, corresponding entries of dfa are repeated accordingly)

```
dfall <- merge(dfa, dfb, by = c("id", "month"), all.y=TRUE)

#     id month sqft traf price frequency day
#1  1027     1    1   31     6       188   1
#2  1027     1    1   31     1       198  15
#3  1027     1    1   31     2       123  30
#4  1027     2    2   31     4       185   1
#5  1027     2    2   31     5       122  15
#6  1030     1   16   35     8       196   1
#7  1030     1   16   35     9       101  15
#8  1030     1   16   35    10       156  30
#9  1030     2   15   32     3       137   1
#10 1030     2   15   32     7       190  15
```

Then, you can use `ddply` as usual:

```
ddply(dfall, .(id, month), mutate, newcol = mean(price)/sqft)
#    id month sqft traf price frequency day    newcol
#1  1027     1    1   31     6       188   1 3.0000000
#2  1027     1    1   31     1       198  15 3.0000000
#3  1027     1    1   31     2       123  30 3.0000000
#4  1027     2    2   31     4       185   1 2.2500000
#5  1027     2    2   31     5       122  15 2.2500000
#6  1030     1   16   35     8       196   1 0.5625000
#7  1030     1   16   35     9       101  15 0.5625000
#8  1030     1   16   35    10       156  30 0.5625000
#9  1030     2   15   32     3       137   1 0.3333333
#10 1030     2   15   32     7       190  15 0.3333333
```

Edit: if you're looking for better performance, consider using `dplyr` instead of `plyr`. The equivalent dplyr code (including the merge) is:

```
library(dplyr)

dfall <- dfb %>% 
  left_join(., dfa, by = c("id", "month")) %>%
  group_by(id, month) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(newcol = mean(price)/sqft)   # I added dplyr:: to avoid confusion with plyr::mutate
```

Of course, you could also check out `data.table` which is also very efficient.

AFAIK `ddply` is not designed to be used with different data frames at the same time.

Comment: thanks - this works, especially for this sample data. However, would there be a better if I had say 500 or 1000 entries in Dataframe B for every id? Especially if I were making many new columns?

Comment: I doubt that that it would be better to use two separate data.frames in a single ddply call. If you are looking for better performance, I recommend checking out `dplyr` instead. I'll update my answer with the equivalent code.

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr` does well here. This code merges the data frames, gets price and sqft means by unique id/month combination, then creates a new variable `pricePerSqft`.

```
require(dplyr)

dfa %>%
  left_join(dfb, by = c("id", "month")) %>%
  group_by(id, month) %>%
  summarize(
    avgPrice = mean(price),
    avgSqft = mean(sqft)) %>%
  mutate(pricePerSqft = round(avgPrice / avgSqft, 2))
```

Here's the result:

```
    id month avgPrice avgSqft pricePerSqft
1 1027     1      3.0       1         3.00
2 1027     2      4.5       2         2.25
3 1030     1      9.0      16         0.56
4 1030     2      5.0      15         0.33
```